# how to pass result of a 3 level lapply loop to the global environment

Tags: r, scope, environment, lapply

The problem is the res object (the result of the model, what foo() returns is nos being assigned to the cv object. I guess there is an environment issue that doesn't pass the object. Any ideas?

```
seed_inx <- 1:10
ntree <- seq(1000, 51000, 2500)
maxnodes <- c(seq(50, 900, 50), seq(1000, 10000, 500))

cv <- lapply(seed_inx, function(x1) {
        lapply(ntree, function(x2) {
          lapply(maxnodes, function(x3) {
            print(sprintf("Seed: %s, ntree: %s, max_nd: %s", x1, x2, x3))
            res <- paste(x1, x2, x3)
          })
          return(res)
        })
        return(res)
      })
```

Comment: I get `Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid 'size' argument`

Comment: it's not supposed to be runned as you don't have the data. The question is more conceptual. I just need to "get" the res object inside the loop and assign it to cv.

Comment: If you can't create a reproducible example, it is far more difficult to give a specific answer. It's not clear what isn't working. What's the desired result. Why are you assigning to `res` at all rather than just letting the value bubble up?

Comment: @MartínBel: then why adding it to the question at all? Add something that works, and is simple.

Comment: I'll remove the fit function as it was more confusing than helpful. thx for your aswer @GaborCsardi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code gives

```
# Error in FUN(c(1000, 3500, 6000, 8500, 11000, 13500, 16000, 18500, 21000,  : 
#   object 'res' not found
```

Rightly so, because `res` is local to the inner most `lapply`, so it is destroyed at the end of that anonymous function. But in R, a function returns the value of the last evaluated expression, so all you need to do is removing the assignment, and the explicit `return()` calls. I.e.:

```
cv <- lapply(seed_inx, function(x1) {
        lapply(ntree, function(x2) {
          lapply(maxnodes, function(x3) {
            print(sprintf("Seed: %s, ntree: %s, max_nd: %s", x1, x2, x3))
            paste("foobar", x1, x2, x3)
          })
        })
      })
```

This runs fine:

```
# [1] "Seed: 1, ntree: 1000, max_nd: 50"
# [1] "Seed: 1, ntree: 1000, max_nd: 100"
# [1] "Seed: 1, ntree: 1000, max_nd: 150"
# [...]

cv[[10]][[5]][[5]]
# [1] "foobar 10 11000 250"
```